# Display div one after the another and one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just want to know how to display divs one after another but also one at a time.

So I have this codes where a certain div shows when you hover on another div.

HTML

```
<section class="map">

   <img src="img/map.jpg">

   <div id="vietnam">
    <div id="vietnam-1">Vietnam</div>
   </div>

   <div id="cambodia">
       <div id="cambodia-1">Cambodia</div>
   </div>

   <div id="singapore">
       <div id="singapore-1">Singapore</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.map {
   background: #fff;
   font-size: 1em;
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
   line-height: 2em;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 1
}

#vietnam, #cambodia, #singapore {
   background-image: url(img/pin.png);
   background-size: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 22px;
   position: absolute;
}

#vietnam:hover, #cambodia:hover, #singapore:hover {
   background-image: url(img/bluepin.png);
}

#vietnam {
  top: 43.9%;
  right: 21.8%;
}

#cambodia{
  top: 42.7%;
  right: 22.7%;
}

#singapore {
  top: 51%;
  right:  22.6%
}

#vietnam-1, #cambodia-1, #singapore-1 {
  display: none;
  background:#007eff;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}

#vietnam:hover #vietnam-1, #cambodia:hover #cambodia-1, #singapore:hover #singapore-1 {
  display: block;
  top: 2em;
  position: absolute;   
  right: -4em;
}
```

Now, what I want to happen is that the div that appears on hover will be shown too one after the another, and one at a time. So  like the word Vietnam appears, then after a fews second, it will hide disappear and the word Cambodia will appear, then after a few seconds again, it will disappear and the word Singapore will appear.

How do I achieve this? thanks!

Comment: You need to do that in Javascript, it can't be done just in CSS.

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to perform actions after a few seconds.

Comment: You might be able to use CSS Animations for this.  They will only work in recent browser versions: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Here is a simple example of 3 divs showing one at a time in order: http://jsfiddle.net/lexingtonpenguins/54rmS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Lookt at

[.animate() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

You can do a function to call recursively (I didn't test this code):

```
animateDivs = function(divIdArray, position) {
  if(position == null) {
    position = 0;
  }
  var divId = divIdArray[position++];
  $( "#" + divId).animate({
    width: "toggle",
    height: "toggle"
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: "linear",
      height: "easeOutBounce"
    },
    complete: function() {
      animateDivs(divIdArray, position);
    }
  });
};
```

Then call the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  animateDivs(["vietnam", "cambodia", "singapore"]);
});
```

(I didn't test this code!) Improve it yourself ;)